# Entity Framework connecting to SQLEXPRESS not SQL Compact

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have been trying out a code first EF project with SQl Compact 4.0.
When I try running the project I get an error that "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.".

I searched for help and in response to a few blogs tried to identify the connection string being used. To my surprise it was

```
context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString    "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ancestors.Models.AncestorsContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"    string
```

even though my web.config file includes the following sections...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"    connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Ancestors-20121012114712.sdf" /> 
</connectionStrings>

<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Has anyone any idea why EF is insisting on creating a connection to SQLEXPRESS instead of SQL Compact?
I can find no reference at all to SQLEXPRESS anywhere in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the following to pass your connection name to the DBContext

```
public YourContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
{

}
```

Use the name directive

```
public YourContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
{

}
```

This will tell EF to use the parameter as a connection.

Also Adding the "clear" at the top of your connectionStrings sections in web.config may resolve inheritance issues.

Comment: For EF6 if you add `name` to the context you get an error `"Connection with that name not found"`

Answer (score 2):

Look for the `<entityFramework>` section in your web.Config, it should have your default connection factory there:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
```

If you're doing a code first project, you can also alter your default constructor to use your other connection string:

```
public YourContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
{

}
```

Comment: The <entityFramework> section is as follows...  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>

Comment: Try adding a value to your defaultConnectionFactory with your connection string, or alter your default constructor so that it's targeting your other connection string

Answer (score 1):

This blog post deals with how to do this...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidobando/archive/2013/03/13/10339621.aspx

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.