# Mono/Linux Entity Framework support

Tags: c#, linux, entity-framework, mono

I've created a very simple test for *Entity Framework*, following the Code first samples in the project's page at *Microsoft's MSDN*.

The Mono compatibility page says that *Entity Framework* is fully supported, so I installed the *NuGET* package. It worked flawlessly.

I created a very simple **Person** class, with its corresponding **PersonContest**.

```
    public class Person {
        public Person(string name, string email)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Email = email;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format( "{0}, {1}", Name, Email );
        }
    }

    public class PersonsContext: DbContext {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }
```

It compiles and runs. But when it is time to save the **Person** objects to the **DbContext** (**PersonsContext**), then it complains with a **Sytem.NotImplementedException** saying "MARS is not implemented".

Can I run *Entity Framework* on Linux with mono or not?

Comment: MARS is Multiple Active Results Sets (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131686.aspx), it may be saying you database doesn't support that which isn't a mono issue. You ought to be able to turn that off in the connection string.

Comment: Related question: [How to disable mars and circumvent mars is not yet implemented exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069403/how-to-disable-mars-and-circumvent-mars-is-not-yet-implemented-exception)

Comment: I haven't set any database for the backend. I guess that's the problem. The database is not configured in the tutorial, either...